# why is that IXSLTemplate::putref_stylesheet compile when passed an IXMLDOMDocument argument

Tags: c++, xml, msxml, xslt

I am playing with XSLT with MSXML2 for the first time. And of course it doesn't work :-)
I have a bug which I cannot figure to solve.

So as to fix the bug, I try to understand everything around: and something shocks me.

```
void xsltProcessing(IXMLDOMDocument* pXmlDoc, IXMLDOMDocument * pXslDoc)
{
    CComPtr<IXSLTemplate> pTemplate;
    pTemplate.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_XSLTemplate);
    pTemplate->putref_stylesheet(pXslDoc);
    //...
}
```

it compiles like a breeze whereas this is the definition of putref_stylesheet

```
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall putref_stylesheet (
    /*[in]*/ struct IXMLDOMNode * stylesheet ) = 0;
```

and I haven't found any definition that would accept a IXMLDOMDocument * as a parameter.

How is that possible to compile ? the two types simply don't match !

any help appreciated.

I have found these two links that also pass xmldocuments in their code !:
[Example One](http://www.ureader.com/msg/1629989.aspx)
[Example Two](http://ubiquity-xforms-cpp.googlecode.com/svn-history/r89/trunk/XFormsProcessor/src/msw/XFormsXPathFunctions.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IXMLDOMDocument` is derived from `IXMLDOMNode` according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757878%28VS.85%29.aspx). Hence it is same as passing a derived class pointer to a class expecting a base class pointer. Hence it compiles.

Comment: mama mia... that essential fact, I didn't know. Glad I have asked this obvious question. thx. I don't know how many times I have used ::QueryInterface to switch between the two... I dare not think about it.